# Swift frameworks do not work with build configurations named other than 'Debug' or 'Release': No such module

Tags: ios, build, swift, frameworks, xcode6

Whenever I try to use a build configuration named other than 'Debug' or 'Release', Xcode suddenly cannot find my Swift frameworks.  The configurations are the exact same other than their name (in fact, the new configuration was duplicated from the working 'Debug' configuration).

[image: Build configurations screenshot]

Xcode reports 'No such module'

[image: Xcode error]

This seems like a really strange bug.  Surely someone has come across this before? My Google search yielded no results.  Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this issue?  I'm pretty sure I added the framework correctly.

I've created a short screencast to show you exactly what I'm doing: http://www.screencast.com/t/zpgZ5ZYgvH

Bottom line:

1. Make sure project currently builds using third-party Swift frameworks
2. Select the project in the project/file navigator
3. Select the project above Targets in the editor left sidebar and make sure you are on the Info tab
4. Duplicate the current configuration (likely 'Debug') by clicking the + button below the list of configurations and selecting 'Duplicate XXX Configuration'
5. Modify your scheme to use the new configuration by going to Product (menu) > Scheme > Edit Scheme...
6. Select Run in the left sidebar
7. Select your new configuration under Build Configuration
8. Attempt to build again

You can also download the sample project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=48797763216274271820

I'm running Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317) and Yosemite 10.10 (14A361c).

Comment: +1 for your efforts ;)

Comment: @someotherguy I'm running into this too... any solution?

Comment: When I add configurations with the same name to the frameworks, it works... so in your case, try adding `Debug Original` to the Alamofire project...

Comment: @JohnGibb No solution yet. =/ Nice catch! I'll try that out soon.

Comment: Tangentially, my understanding is that frameworks are supported only for app extensions, not for code reuse. Unless I'm wrong (or you're using it for an app extension), this means Apple would reject such an app anyway.

Comment: @GregoryHigley Hmm, I don't think that is the case as [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is used in apps in the App Store. Perhaps it depends on how the framework is linked?

Comment: Hm, looks like I'm wrong about that, and glad to be so.

Comment: I have the same issue, but for the simulator only. Did you found a solution yet? I can build for the device, but not the simulator. Any config other than Release or Debug, and so long frameworks e/

Comment: Nope. My builds still fail even when building for an iOS device (and not the simulator).

Comment: So this issue is still around. I didn't have any clue that it might be a bug related to swift as my very first app is swift. :( damn

Comment: I believe it is bug. Apple engineers also agree: https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/717535474789658625. Please dupe my radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/25576298.

Answer (score 35):

Add the following `Framework Search Path` in the `Build Settings` of your target:
`$(SYMROOT)/Release$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`
and make it `non-recursive`

In my case this was for Alamofire, which was added to my project as a git submodule.

The framework was being built correctly which can be seen in the build logs, but I assume the default framework search path is derived from the scheme name. The Alamofire framework & dSYM file are in `Release-iphoneos`/ `Release-iphonesimulator`.

This should work work with any Swift framework as long as it's scheme names are default. If not, check the build logs and adjust the framework search path accordingly.

Comment: THANK YOU. I couldn't find the solution anywhere, and then suddenly I stumbled upon this thread and your answer resolved my issue!

Comment: **this works with Objective-C sub-projects also. And.. thanks for your answer!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! This problem gave me a big headache.

Comment: Wasted so much time on this problem. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 26):

I had this issue as well and fixed it by adding the same configuration names to the included Alamofire project.

My build schemes in my main project:
[image: main project configs]

And the build schemes inside the Alamofire project:
[image: screenshot of schemes]

**Note:**
Also, make sure your iOS deployment target is the same in both projects.

Comment: Thanks for reporting in. Unfortunately this isn't an ideal solution. Hopefully Apple fixes this soon.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to do "Clean (CAP+CMD+K)" to make it work.

Comment: THANK YOU. This saved me hours, I'm sure of it.

Comment: @Antoine: Thanks! In above example you had Alamofire Framework project, so you were able to update build configurations, but if We have only  compiled framework(Without Project) for e.g) HockeySDK.framework, Then we cant update build configurations. How to deal with such situation? Any Idea?

Comment: I had to do this too, changing the Framework Search Path didn't help.

Comment: This works, but feels like a really really ugly hack - should I be able to tell the Xcode, that for this app configuration I want to use the given framework configuration?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using CocoaPods, try `pod install` this will generate some .xcconfig files with your configuration name. Clean your build folder and build again.

Comment: If you use CocoaPods, that is indeed the best option!

Comment: I have the same issue with CocoaPods. In fact, I originally ran into this error first when using CocoaPods. For the purposes of this question, I tried without CocoaPods to rule out CocoaPods as the culprit.

Comment: I had the same issue , this solved the problem. This would be a valid solution if problem is due cocoapods

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to work. CocoaLumberjack is the culprit at the moment

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modular structure (e.g. the App uses frameworks to decouple UI, Services or Business Logic from the application's main module) then add the new Build Configuration to each subproject that builds these frameworks.

In this case if the author had, let's say, Services Framework in his workspace then he had to add a Debug Original configuration to it too. And then run `pod install`, of course.

This is how I fixed my issue.