# Cocoapods -lPods-{pod name} mach-o linker error

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

Using multiple schemes for build project, i'm getting this error across all scheme archiving processes:

```
Ld /Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/project.build/ReleaseProd-iphoneos/project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/project normal arm64
    cd /Users/daniel.kim/Projects/7-11/project-ios-2-0
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/BuildProductsPath/ReleaseProd-iphoneos -L/Users/daniel.kim/Projects/7-11/project-ios-2-0/Pods/FlurrySDK/Flurry -F/Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/BuildProductsPath/ReleaseProd-iphoneos -filelist /Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/project.build/ReleaseProd-iphoneos/project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/project.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lFlurry_5.4.0 -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-AFOAuth2Client -lPods-AsyncImageView -lPods-Bugsnag -lPods-FXPageControl -lPods-FlurrySDK -lPods-ISO8601DateFormatter -lPods-MBProgressHUD -lPods-MMDrawerController -lPods-Mantle -lPods-RSBarcodes -lc++ -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework StoreKit -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -force_load -Xlinker /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/project.build/ReleaseProd-iphoneos/project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/project.swiftmodule -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/project.build/ReleaseProd-iphoneos/project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/project_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/daniel.kim/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/project-dmzuaarzxovfpwglmdnamvbivecp/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/project-release-prod/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/project.build/ReleaseProd-iphoneos/project.build/Objects-normal/arm64/project

ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using the xcworkspace, have tried a fresh pod install, have gem updated system as well as cocoapods, change associated values to $(inherited) in things such as the library search paths, checked the schemes to ensure that there were no extraneous processes for each and every scheme.

The schemes are only used to change environment variables for our test / production API servers when it's a debug versus release build.

Have tried changing every possible related setting in xcode that I could think of.

**UPDATE:** As a note, the first scheme doesn't fail when building, with is my debug-prod scheme. It archives and works successfully. There is some mention on the troubleshooting cocoapods page about only the first target being specific automatically by cocoapods and that link_with needs to be used to specify other targets, but all I have is 4 schemes and one target, not 4 targets...

What do i need to do to specify and direct cocoapods to those builds?

Answer (score 2):

Under `Edit Scheme -> Archive -> Archive -> Build Configuration`, just need to set the proper configuration...

That solved the issue, they were all pointed to the wrong default Build Configs created by XCode `Debug` or `Release`....

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your other imported xcode project implemented these custom schemes as well. 
More information can be found in my post here:

[Swift frameworks do not work with build configurations named other than 'Debug' or 'Release': No such module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073088/swift-frameworks-do-not-work-with-build-configurations-named-other-than-debug/27527246#27527246)

Comment: So after looking at that link, I did notice something slightly off in that I have 4 configurations for my actual project, which are: [ DebugProd, DebugTest, ReleaseProd, ReleaseTest], but my Pods project configuration also has in addition to those aforementioned [Debug, Release]...

Comment: Have your tried to do a clean install of your pods? (remove podfile.lock & pods folder, pod install). Also, you can try to add the targets to your podfile by adding link_with 'Target1', 'Target2'. More about this here: http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html

Comment: Yes, I have tried doing a clean install with removing the aforementioned files and folders.

As for link_with, as mentioned in my update in my original post, I only have one target, which is <project>, and <project>Tests, the rest of the schemes dont' point to their own targets.  I think this is where I'm slipping up as I've never configured schemes with cocoapods before.

Comment: Strange behaviour.. The only solution I can think of is to copy your working configuration 'debug-prod' and use that as a base for your other configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by making sure each scheme was visible (Product->Scheme->Manage Schemes->Tick 'Show' or each pod). Then I built each pod project individually.

After that I could build my project. I cannot explain why this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was that I was opening the wrong file. Make sure you open your .xcworkspace file.