# iOS - Custom Configuration - "No such module"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

In my ios app, I'm trying to distinguish environments, to make web api calls to the proper environment (`Development`, `Staging` and `Production`).

For that I have created a `configuration.plist` file with the different endpoints for each environment and:

- Duplicated the `Debug` Configuration and called it `Development Build`.
- Created a new Scheme called `Development` (duplicated the `Debug` scheme)
  and in the Info tab (`Run` section) chose the `Development Build`
  configuration.

When I run in Debug mode, everything runs normally.

I'm using cocoa pods.

If I select `Development` scheme, I get a `No such module 'JazzHands'`

If I edit the `Development` scheme to use the `Debug` build, it works fine.

So I must be missing some thing for this not to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift frameworks do not work with build configurations named other than 'Debug' or 'Release': No such module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26073088/swift-frameworks-do-not-work-with-build-configurations-named-other-than-debug)

Comment: That sure looks like it.

Answer (score 17):

For those running into this question, try `pod install` this will generate some .xcconfig files with your configuration name. Clean your build folder and build again.

This worked for me with Cocoapods 1.0

Comment: This is the correct answer, worked for me. CocoaPods 1.5.3

Answer (score 6):

## Solution:

Create the same custom build configuration in `JazzHands`

## Root cause:

- Compilation error `No such module` is thrown because it can't locate the `JazzHands` for your custom build configuration

## Background:

- Every time you compile a folder is created in `DerivedData`.
- This folder corresponds to your device / simulator and your app.
- Inside this folder there would be a `Build` folder which would contain  a folder corresponding to each build configuration for your project.
- In your case `Development` folder would not contain the framework `JazzHands` binary
- However `Debug` folder would contain the framework `JazzHands` binary

## Example:

Given below is an example:

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeApp-skjahjkdhsakjhdaskjdhaskjlhs/Build/Development-iphonesimulator`

- SomeApp - Name of the app
- Development - Custom Build configuration