# Fastlane match build adhoc and appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-match, fastlane-gym

I'm using Fastlane [match](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#match) and [gym](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/build_app/#build_app) for building and distributing my app from a CI (Bitrise) to Fabric. My Xcode settings are set to manual with a Release configuration using the AdHoc profile as described in the [Fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/xcode-project/#xcode-9-and-up)

Now I want to distribute to the Appstore from the CI but it fails because Xcode `Release` config is set to use the AdHoc profile and Match installed the AppStore profile.

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           Summary for gym 2.112.0                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                                                        | AeroNavMap                                                                  |
| export_method                                                 | app-store                                                                   |
| export_xcargs                                                 | -allowProvisioningUpdates                                                   |
| export_options.provisioningProfiles.net.tequilaapps.airnavmap | match AppStore net.tequilaapps.airnavmap                                    |
| workspace                                                     | ./PEMap.xcworkspace                                                         |
| destination                                                   | generic/platform=iOS                                                        |
| output_name                                                   | AeroNavMap                                                                  |
| build_path                                                    | /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-01-06                  |
| clean                                                         | false                                                                       |
| output_directory                                              | .                                                                           |
| silent                                                        | false                                                                       |
| skip_package_ipa                                              | false                                                                       |
| result_bundle                                                 | false                                                                       |
| buildlog_path                                                 | /var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/fastlane_logs957341986/gym |
| skip_profile_detection                                        | false                                                                       |
| xcode_path                                                    | /Applications/Xcode.app                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[13:47:38]: $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./PEMap.xcworkspace -scheme AeroNavMap -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/vagrant/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-01-06/AeroNavMap\ 2019-01-06\ 13.47.38.xcarchive archive | tee /var/folders/90/5stft2v13fb_m_gv3c8x9nwc0000gn/T/fastlane_logs957341986/gym/AeroNavMap-AeroNavMap.log | xcpretty
[13:47:42]: ▸ ❌  error: No profile for team 'XXXXXXXX' matching 'match AdHoc net.tequilaapps.airnavmap' found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching 'G9MA9G2SST/match AdHoc net.tequilaapps.airnavmap'. Install the profile (by dragging and dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the General tab of the target editor. (in target 'AeroNavMap')
[13:47:42]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED *
```

This all makes sense but the question is how am I supposed to setup Xcode so that I can have two Fastlane lanes, one for building for AppStore, the other for AdHoc.

I *could* create a new Xcode config `AppStore` where I'd set the AppStore provisioning profile but this rises an other issue where my custom Frameworks don't build. Similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520503/ios-custom-configuration-no-such-module). I have many custom Frameworks and I would need to create that same `AppStore` configuration in their Xcode project as well but that is too much of a hack solution.

I tried forcing `gym` to use the AppStore profile as follows but that does not help. The AdHoc profile set in Xcode is still being used.

```
  desc "Builds the app for the AppStore"
  lane :build_appstore do
      match(type: "appstore", readonly: true)
      build_app(
          scheme: "AeroNavMap",
          export_method: "app-store", 
          skip_profile_detection: true,
          export_options: { provisioningProfiles: { "net.tequilaapps.airnavmap" => "match AppStore net.tequilaapps.airnavmap"}}
          )
  end
```

My current solution is to manually update the xcodeproj just before building but this is also not very clean

```
  lane :build_appstore do
      match(type: "appstore", readonly: true)
      if Helper.ci? 
        UI.message "Patching Xcode proj to use AppStore profile"
        `sed -i.bak -e 's/match AdHoc net.tequilaapps.airnavmap/match AppStore net.tequilaapps.airnavmap/g' ../PEMap/PEMap.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`
      end
      build_app(scheme: "AeroNavMap", export_method: "app-store")
  end
```

Comment: Did you find any elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

There are two code signing phases when you archive a build (using Xcode or gym): the code signing identity used when building (in Xcode that's what set in the build settings of your target) and the one used when exporting the archive (the one you select in the export dialog from the organizer when exporting the archive via Xcode manually)

What we do in our Fastfiles is set both to the same value when invoking gym. We override the build settings using xcargs and use there the same signing as the one we set in export_options:

```
MY_APP_ID = "com.foo.bar"
MY_PROFILE = "match AppStore com.foo.bar"
MY_TEAM = …

match(
    app_identifier: MY_APP_ID,
    type: "appstore",
    readonly: true
)

settings_to_override = {
  :BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER => MY_APP_ID,
  :PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER => MY_PROFILE,
  :DEVELOPMENT_TEAM => MY_TEAM
}

gym(
    workspace: WORKSPACE_PATH,
    scheme: "Foo",
    configuration: "Production",
    xcargs: settings_to_override,
    export_method: "app-store",
    export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: { 
            MY_APP_ID => MY_PROFILE
        }
    }
)
```

Credit to https://github.com/AliSoftware